# How to add Null Character in CSV using Python with no format change

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, null, export-to-csv

Hello I would like to know how to write a null character on CSV using Python (without changing the format

My CSV logs the data I've set on an application.

But when I output a null character, The whole row moves and the null character does not consider.

""" Write data to output CSV File"""

```
if self.Input.Logging_Active.value:
    if hasattr(self,'OutputFile'):
        for f in self.fields[:-1]: #all but last elements
            WriteFieldtoFile(self.OutputFile,f,",")
        WriteFieldtoFile(self.OutputFile,self.fields[-1],"\n"  #last elemtent
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fsG0.png)

Comment: The screenshot looks like some viewer. Is that viewer capable of properly handling nulls? Did you actually check the raw file whether it includes the Null bytes?

Comment: what do you use to keep data and save it? Better don't create csv file manually but use modules like `csv` or `pandas` for this.